# Vimgrep mapping not working

Tags: vim, grep, mapping

If I run manually the command

```
:vimgrep /\CTODO:\|FIXME:\|NOTE:/ %
```

everything works as expected. However when i try the following mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>tl :vimgrep /\CTODO:\|FIXME:\|NOTE:/ %<CR>
```

I get the error:

> E480: No match: \CTODO:|FIXME:|NOTE:

I don't why the map is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`|` is used to separated vim commands. You have escaped the `|` to treat the pipe as one command however this changes regex  into `\CTODO:|FIXME:|NOTE:` Look at the mapping via `:nmap` to see how the mapping has changed.

I suggest you use `<bar>` instead of the pipe symbol in your mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>tl :vimgrep /\CTODO:\<bar>FIXME:\<bar>NOTE:/ %<CR>
```